# Write to file descriptor 3 of a Python subprocess.Popen object

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I write to file descriptor 3 of a subprocess.Popen object?

I'm trying to accomplish the redirection in the following shell command with Python (without using named pipes):

```
$ gpg --passphrase-fd 3 -c 3<passphrase.txt < filename.txt > filename.gpg
```

Comment: I'm curious to know this. I don't think it's directly possible. The `Popen` objects offer handles to stdout, stdin and stderr. I don't know about others.

Comment: Perhaps OT, but are you aware of the python-gnupg project which provides a Python API for GnuPG? See http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/ for more info. (Disclosure: it's my project)

Comment: I looked into some Python gpg wrappers, and yours looks quite viable, but my current project is so small that I'm trying to minimize dependencies.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. But it looks like python subprocess module is still not as capable as simple shell redirection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subprocess `proc` inherits file descriptors opened in the parent process.
So you can use `os.open` to open passphrase.txt and obtain its associated file descriptor. You can then construct a command which uses that file descriptor:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import os

fd=os.open('passphrase.txt',os.O_RDONLY)
cmd='gpg --passphrase-fd {fd} -c'.format(fd=fd)
with open('filename.txt','r') as stdin_fh:
    with open('filename.gpg','w') as stdout_fh:        
        proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),
                              stdin=stdin_fh,
                              stdout=stdout_fh)        
        proc.communicate()
os.close(fd)
```

---

To read from a pipe instead of a file, you could use `os.pipe`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import os

PASSPHRASE='...'

in_fd,out_fd=os.pipe()
os.write(out_fd,PASSPHRASE)
os.close(out_fd)
cmd='gpg --passphrase-fd {fd} -c'.format(fd=in_fd)
with open('filename.txt','r') as stdin_fh:
    with open('filename.gpg','w') as stdout_fh:        
        proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),
                              stdin=stdin_fh,
                              stdout=stdout_fh )        
        proc.communicate()
os.close(in_fd)
```

Comment: cool.  so if i didn't want to keep the passphrase in a file, i could create a pipe, write the passphrase to it, and use it's output fd as the inherited file descriptor where gpg would get the passphrase?

Comment: @aaronstacy: Yes, I tested it to be sure. (code posted above)

Comment: Note that there is a theoretical danger of deadlocking if the password is larger than the OS's pipe buffer. To be safe, you'd have to do IO multiplexing, and write the password after launching the process.

Comment: A quick update: In Python 3, `close_fds` is `True` by default, so you'll want to add `pass_fds=[in_fd]` to that `Popen` constructor to make it work.

Comment: To explain a bit: in Python it's not possible to do things like "connect file descriptor 3 of child to file descriptor 4 of parent"; *however* in this particular case (for example) the code opens file descriptor 4 from `passphrase.txt`, then use `pass_fds` to connect fd4 of child to fd4 of parent, then tell the child to read from file descriptor 4 instead of 3. // It remains possible to e.g. invoke bash from Python, which redirect the fds properly for the children.