# More woes with subprocess, lists

Tags: python, list, subprocess

I have the following code

```
clearfile = '/tmp/jjj'
passphrase = "one fish two fish"

opts = '--no-tty --homedir=/www/vhost/.gnupg --passphrase-fd 0 -a -c -o - '
cmd = ['/usr/bin/gpg', opts, clearfile ]

print opts
print cmd

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = proc.communicate(passphrase)
gpgdata = out.read()
out.close()

print gpgdata
```

I know the read bit is wrong, but the command fails as it truncates the opts and I get the following error

```
gpg: invalid option "--no-tty --homedir=/www/vhost/.gnupg --passphrase-"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test", line 26, in <module>
    gpgdata = out.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

why is the opts string being truncated?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: each item in the list should be a *separate* program argument: `cmd = shlex.split('/usr/bin/gpg --no-tty --homedir=/www/vhost/.gnupg --passphrase-fd 0 -a -c -o - ') + [clearfile]` (add `import shlex` at the top)

Comment: `out` is already a string; don't call `out.read()` Have you tried to run it?

Comment: Yes I finally figured out that they should hall be separate bits.
Still fighting with the subprocess bits. Thanks all.

Comment: Ron, you should edit the question.  That `comment code` is illegible.

Comment: Yes it hangs, but I suspect I am not handling the output properly

Comment: @jamie I deleted it - sorry for the noise.

Comment: related: [gpg --passphrase-fd not working with python 3 subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20312715/4279)

Answer (score 0):

You should Read the Fine Manual :

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen

> subprocess.Popen(args) : args should be a sequence of program
>   arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute
>   is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string,
>   the interpretation is platform-dependent [ ... ] **Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass
>   args as a sequence.**

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```