# Encrypt file with GPG in python 3 with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, subprocess, gnupg

How do I encrypt file with subprocess, so the output will be string.

```
 password = '%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)
 encrypted_file = subprocess.geststatusoutput("echo "+password+
 "|gpg --password-fd 0 < "+ name_of_selected_file)
```

I want to encrypted _file to be a string so I could use it as encrypted file to upload with post request.
What is the best way to do it with gnupg library?

Comment: i have never tried it - but there is a python library to gpg: https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/ .

Comment: I don't want to use another external library just for something what can be simply scripted.

Comment: There are very good reasons _not_ to interface GnuPG manually. Passing the passphrase like you do is one of them, everybody on your system will be able to read it while GnuPG is working by reading the command line arguments. It also takes care of a whole bunch of other probem that can and will occur, including proper error handling.

Comment: related: [gpg --passphrase-fd not working with python 3 subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318581/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to execute a gpg command like this:

```
import shlex
import random
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

passphrase = '%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)
source_filename = '/tmp/somefile'
cmd = 'gpg --batch --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 0 --output - {}'.format(source_filename)

# error handling omitted
p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
encrypted_data = p.communicate(passphrase.encode())[0]

# Decryption - should work for Python 2 & 3
import os

r, w = os.pipe()    # pipe for sending passphrase from parent to child
try:
    os.set_inheritable(r, True)
except AttributeError:      # new in version 3.4
    pass
cmd = 'gpg --batch --decrypt --passphrase-fd {}'.format(r)
p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=False)
os.close(r)    # closes fd in parent, child needs it
f = os.fdopen(w, 'w')
f.write(passphrase + '\n')    # '\n' seems required for Python 2 ???
f.close()
decrypted_data, stderr = p.communicate(encrypted_data)

# check that data was successfully roundtripped
assert open(source_filename).read() == decrypted_data.decode()
```

Or, decryption for Python 3 only:

```
import os
r, w = os.pipe()
cmd = 'gpg --batch --decrypt --passphrase-fd {}'.format(r)
p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, pass_fds=(r,))
os.close(r)    # closes fd in parent, child needs it
open(w, 'w').write(passphrase)
decrypted_data, stderr = p.communicate(encrypted_data)

# check that data was successfully roundtripped
assert open(source_filename).read() == decrypted_data.decode()
```

Now I am not an expert on the security of this method, however, writing the passphrase directly to the child process' stdin with [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is better than echoing the passphrase on the command line - which would be visible to anybody that could run `ps` or equivalent.

Also, relying on the shell level IO redirection of your command would require the `shell=True` argument to Popen which might have other security implications (see the warning in the `Popen()` documentation).

I have assumed in my `gpg` command that you are intending to use a symmetric encryption (your example does not suggest otherwise). If the remote server needs to be able to decrypt the encrypted file content, how are you going to share the generated passphrase?

You might be better off looking at using public key crypto instead.

Comment: "how are you going to share the generated passphrase?" That's a good point.

Comment: Mainly I use it in my tool for uploading file so the link to the file would be http://somesite.some/somefile!passkey, as I use public site, then decrypting the file with similar method.

Comment: your code won't work on Python 3. You could pass `passphrase = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(15)).zfill(30)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian is right this code won't work. Now I'm really considering finding a sollution with gnupg library.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - thanks, I overlooked the Python 3 requirement. Nevertheless and easy fix is to pass `passphrase.encode()` as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: @MikołajSzymonHalber : fixed to work with Python3, or you could use the method of generating the passphrase suggested by J.F.Sebastian.

Comment: @mhawke Now script works if the --batch options is added and then there is no popup for password, now I need a way to decrypt without a popup.

Comment: Decryption is pretty similar. however, because the encrypted data is sent to the child's stdin, you need to send the passphrase from parent to child  over a new pipe. I've added a general Python solution to my answer as well as a Python 3 only version.

Comment: The big problem with decryption for my program is that I will need to decrypt not a file, but data stream so more piping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83765/discussion-between-mikolaj-szymon-halber-and-mhawke).

Comment: The code that I posted does decrypt a stream. `encrypted_data` is being passed to the gpg child process via `communicate()`. This is going to the child's stdin.