# How do I use file descriptors other than std[in/out/err]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, file-descriptor

I need to pipe two streams of data to an external program from a Python (3.4) script. One can go to STDIN, and I'm ok on that:

```
from subprocess import check_output

data1 = b'This is the data to pass on stdin'
check_output(['externalprogram'], input=data1)
```

The program can accept the other piece on a file descriptor given on the command line, but how do I tell python to send data on another fd?

```
data2 = b'This is the data to pass on fd 3'
check_output(['externalprogram', '-data2fd', '3'], input=data1, ???)
```

I imagine I may need to go a layer deeper and use `Popen`, but I still don't see how to do it.

Comment: use `pass_fds` parameter, [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318581/4279)

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of some combination of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050187/write-to-file-descriptor-3-of-a-python-subprocess-popen-object) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312715/gpg-passphrase-fd-not-working-with-python-3-subprocess/20318581#20318581).

Comment: it is not a duplicate if it is a combination. Have you considered passing `0` (stdin) as `-data2fd` parameter ([I've updated the example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318581/4279))? You could [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, the first link's Q is pretty much exactly what I'm asking. It's just that the second link's answer more directly answered it for Python 3.

Comment: the first link doesn't work on Python 3 ((a) different default for `close_fds` (b) [file descriptors are non-inheritable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/) by default)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Right, but it's still the same question. I think a better idea would be to post a Python 3 version of the answer to the existing question (since it doesn't specify Python 2). That way both answers are in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

On linux at least, you can use `os.pipe` to create a pipe. When the child is called, it inherits the parent pipe. The parent should close the read end to avoid spurious signals, then write to the write side of the pipe. The child can then read from the read end of the pipe.

Comment: That's a helpful prod in the right direction, but I'm still not able to make it work... keep getting a broken pipe exception. Can you provide a short sample snippet?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I just figured it out. +1 for the push in the right direction... if you want to flesh it out, go ahead; otherwise I may post a second answer myself with more info once I've got a full solution.

Comment: `close_fds=True` by default on POSIX in Python 3. You need `pass_fds` parameter here.