# redirect output of jar file in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to redirect the output of my jar in a file with python I have tried the following but it didn't work out

```
import sys
import subprocess

cmdargs = sys.argv
fname = str(cmdargs[1])
input = '../res/test/'+fname
output = '../res/res/'+fname
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '../res/chemTagger2.jar',input,'>',output])
```

the output is print in the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to file descriptor 3 of a Python subprocess.Popen object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050187/write-to-file-descriptor-3-of-a-python-subprocess-popen-object) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the `subprocess.Popen` `stdout` and `stderr` by using their parameters within the `Popen` command, as follows:

```
import sys
import subprocess

cmdargs = sys.argv
fname = str(cmdargs[1])
input = '../res/test/' + fname
output = '../res/res/' + fname

with open(output, 'a') as f_output:
    subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '../res/chemTagger2.jar',input], stdout=f_output)
```